# Navigation bar flashes when cancelling back swipe

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a pretty simple setup:

The root view controller has the navigation bar hidden, and the secondary view controller (`Settings`) has the navigation bar shown with a large title. To achieve the hiding and showing of the navigation bar, I do this:

In the root view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

That's it. And this works perfectly *except* for this special case: When I pan right as if I am dismissing the secondary view controller but then pan back left to cancel, the navigation bar flashes while the secondary view controller animates back as it should. Here is what this looks like in slo-mo:

[image: screengrab]

This same exact thing happens if I move the navigation bar hiding into the secondary view controller's `viewWillAppear(_:)`.

How can I stop the flashing and make this work right?

Comment: Do you really need to make it appear/disappear with animation? Have you tried setting `navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden` instead?

Comment: @GustavoBarbosa, that doesn't work because then when I drag at all the navigation bar disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I do not have a solution, exactly, I have figured out what caused the problem:

If you set the status bar to be hidden in addition to the navigation bar, the navigation bar will jump like in the video in the OP.

The solution for my personal case was basically to hide the status bar only in `viewDidAppear`. The downside is that means that the status bar alpha does not animate when you drag.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. It still gets visible while dismissing the view